A bufferline that spans multiple lines, which behaves like a normal window?
I'm basically looking for an alternative to Vuffers.nvim which shows a buffer list vertically. I want a horizontal list which can be multiple lines long, the Vuffers window can be navigated like a regular buffer, and I can press enter on the line for the buffer I want to switch to.
That combined with hop.nvim, I have a keymap which does the following:

Wwitch to the Vuffers window which I always have on the top left with edgy
Activate hop.nvim to put letter hints on each line
Type the letters for which buffer I want to switch to, and press enter to switch.

I find more efficient than a plugin like Harpoon or :Telescope buffers, where I would have to write a bunch of characters then enter for the buffer I want to switch to. With what I described above I only have to press the keymap, then 1-2 character hints for the buffer I want.

Here's a simple "buffer list navigator" using the quickfix list, assuming your errorformat contains %f:%l:%m:
:cexpr getbufinfo()->map('v:val.name')->filter('!empty(v:val)')->map({_, v -> v..":1:"..v})

This drops the named buffers into a quickfix list (each entry takes you to the first line, unfortunately), but it's easily navigable. With a little more effort (?), you could instead get each buffer's ` mark line number and use that, if you prefer.
A more sophisticated approach would do something like
:new
" set up scratch window options
:put =execute('ls')
:nnoremap <buffer> <enter> :buffer <C-r><C-f><enter>

Both are searchable (for example, /), filterable (example: :global, :Cfilter), etc.

If you like the argument list, then :vimgrep /\%1l/ ## will give you a similar quickfix list on the first line for all the arguments.

Not exactly you want but close.
I'using wilder.nvim which offer a vertical command completion menu with fuzzy logic.
The typing :b  plus some of the buffer letters and you get a short list of the buffers that match the criteria that you could browse with tab or select with Enter




You could be interested by the following bufexplorer plugin.

It works more like a split windows than like a project drawer (see: split windows vs. project drawer but this philosophy has its own advantages :-)
Other candidates could be:

minibufexpl.vim
bufstop

